# Proove that the set A= \{ $x^{2}+x\cdot y^{2}$ : $-2 \leq x \leq 1, -1\leq y \leq 1$ } is bounded above and below

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let A be the set  A= { $x^{2}+x\cdot y^{2}$ : $-2 \leq x \leq 1, -1\leq y \leq 1$ }

Determine wether the set A, subset of the reals is bounded above, below both or neither. Rigorously justify your answer.

Notes : I'm not allowed to use limits or calculus . So far I've found A is bounded above and below simply by minimising and maximising the values of x and y, however I don't think this is rigorous enough. Is there any more formal proof showing that the set is bounded above and below ? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Finding the extremes of the function $f(x,y)=x^2+xy^2$ on the compact domain $[-2,1]\times [-1,1]$ is perfectly rigorous. But the answer by bat_of_doom is the easy way.

Comment: The set $A$ is the image of a continuous function (i.e., $(x,y)\mapsto x^2+xy^2$) on a connected compact set (i.e., $[-2,1]\times[-1,1]$).  Therefore, $A$ is also a connected compact set.  Being a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, $A$ is a closed finite interval.  In fact, it is easy to see that $A=\left[-\frac14,4\right]$.

Comment: @Batominovski  Thank you :)

Comment: @Mathematician42 Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need a lower and upper bound, not the greatest and least respectively.For that, $$|x^2+xy^2|\leq |x|^2+|x||y|^2\leq4+2=6$$, and you are done.

Comment: To the OP: Note that you do not need an accurate estimate just to show boundedness. When trying to stay below $\infty$ and above $-\infty,$  any bounds will do as long as they're finite.

Comment: Thank you, and by that you can show that the set A has a range less than or equal to  6 right ?

Comment: @Sonia Also, greater than equal to -6. (Mind the modulus.) So, -6 serves as a lower bound and +6 as upper.

Answer (score 1):

A pedestrian approach:

1) Lower bound of $A = x^2 + xy^2$ , where $-2 \leq x \leq 1$ and $-1\leq y \leq 1$.

Let $ \alpha: = y^2$, then $0\leq \alpha \leq 1$.

Consider:

A($\alpha$ )= $x^2$ + $\alpha$ x =

= $( x + \alpha /2)^2$ - $\alpha^2$  / 4.

This is a family of parabolas, $\alpha$ the parameter, with 
minimum = - $\alpha ^2$ / 4, $\\$
at ($-\alpha$ /2, -$\alpha ^2 $ / 4).

Choose $\alpha$ = 1 (y= +1 or y = -1) to find the curve with the smallest minimum of the family of  $\alpha$ curves.

Finally:

$$A(\alpha) = (x+\alpha /2)^2 - \alpha ^2 / 4   \geq  \\  
 -\alpha ^2 / 4 \geq - 1/4 .$$

2) Upper bound for A in the given x,y interval,
 a bit of patchwork.

Consider the intervals  - 2 $\leq$ x $\leq$ 0,  and  -1 $\leq$ y $ \leq$ 1 ,  I.e. $ \alpha$ $\geq$ 0.

$A(\alpha) = x^2 + \alpha x \leq A(\alpha=0) = x^2$ , recall that $\alpha \geq 0$, so the left hand side is smaller than $ x^2$ for negative x.

A($\alpha$) $\leq x^2 $, for - 2 $\leq$ x $\leq 0 $,

Setting x = - 2  gives A($\alpha$) $\leq$ A($\alpha$ = 0) = 4   in the intervals considered.

Almost done.

Now consider the remaining interval 0 $\leq$ x $\leq$ 1, $\alpha$ as before.

$$A(\alpha) = x^2 + \alpha x \leq A(\alpha = 1) = \\ =  x^2 + 1x ,$$ where all the x terms are positive (or zero) and $\alpha = 1$.

The maximum for A($\alpha=1$) = 2 at x=1.

For the complete interval -2 $\leq$ x $\leq$ 1, with $\alpha$  (y) in the given range:

Maximum = max( 2,4) = 4 .

Answer (score 0):

Your $x\in[-2,1]$ and $y\in[-1,1]$ is a compact set. $x^2+xy^2$ is a continuous function so that both minimizing and maximizing $x^2+xy^2$ over the set has a solution. Set lower and upper bound equal to $x^2+xy^2$ evaluated at the minimum and maximum respectively.